# How to run the function only once at time

Tags: java

I've application that is on spring boot aplication, I would like to secure this function in such a way that during the life of one application, the function can work only once at a time.

I've tried two things - one from the another topic on stackvoerflow, and it not works.

```
Validator.run(() -> foo());
```

```
    private AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean();
    public void run(Runnable task) {
        if (done.get()) return;
        if (done.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            task.run();
        }
    }
```

and the second one

```
private boolean alreadyExecuted = false; // as member
void foo(){
   if (!alreadyExecuted) {
      alreadyExecuted = true;
      doStuff();
      alreadyExecuted = false;
   }
}
```

The first way anyways allow function to work severals time at once, and the second way dont work at all. Any advice?

Comment: In your second approach create the variable alreadyExecuted to static. So that it is associated to class rather than object. That should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make your method a [synchronized method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

For example:

```
synchronized void doStuff() {
   // Do stuff
}
```